# Convert all ntext columns to nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, alter-table, cursors

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to convert all `ntext` columns in my database to `nvarchar(max)`.

This is the code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SL_ConvertNtextToNvarchar]
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(128)
  DECLARE @column_name nvarchar(128)
  DECLARE @totalCount int
  DECLARE @count int

  SET @totalCount = 0;
  SET @count = 0;
 
  -- Eventlogic
  DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR 

    SELECT so.name as table_name, sc.name as column_name
      FROM sys.objects so
      JOIN sys.columns sc ON so.object_id = sc.object_id
      JOIN sys.types stp ON sc.user_type_id = stp.user_type_id
                        AND stp.name = 'ntext'
     WHERE so.type = 'U' -- to show only user tables
  OPEN tables_cursor
  
  FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @table_name, @column_name
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    EXEC ('ALTER TABLE Eventlogic.dbo.' + @table_name + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @column_name + ' nvarchar(max);')
    EXEC ('UPDATE Eventlogic.dbo.' + @table_name + ' SET ' + @column_name + '=' + @column_name + ' ')
    SET @count = @count + 1;
    IF @count > 0
      PRINT ('Eventlogic.dbo.' + @table_name + '.' + @column_name + ' ' + CAST(@count AS nvarchar(10)))
    SET @totalCount = @totalCount  + @count;
    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @table_name, @column_name
  END 
  CLOSE tables_cursor
  DEALLOCATE tables_cursor
  PRINT ('Total columns updated: ' + CAST(@totalCount AS nvarchar(10)))  
  
END;
```

Whenever I try to run it, I get this error:

> Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_SL_ConvertNtextToNvarchar, Line 37
> Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

We have 338 columns across different tables as `ntext`, due to legacy.

We upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2, so we would like to convert these columns to `nvarchar(max)`.

We want to follow the advice here [ntext vs nvarchar(max)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125040904/http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsperfblog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx) where Conwell suggests to do the update after the alter.

> SQL server moves the text from the LOB structure to the table (if less than 8,000 bytes).  So when we run the select again with IO STATISTICS we get 0 LOB reads.

Any help with this error would be great.

**UPDATE**

Updated code as Martin mentioned.
It is actually altering only the first one on the list before giving the error.

**2nd UPDATE**

After making the changes on the code to fix the second fetch, I closed SQL Management Studio.
Opened SQL Management Studio again and run it and it worked. So thanks Martin again.

Thanks in advance.

Federico

Comment: Your second fetch is just `FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @table_name` it should be `INTO @table_name, @column_name`. Also do you never use schemas other than `dbo`? And you should use `QUOTENAME` around the object names. And you aren't preserving the original column nullability. Do they all allow `NULL`?

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for such a quick response! I'm fairly new at this and always used dbo, is there an advantage on usinng schema? Not sure what QUOTENAME is.

Comment: @MartinSmith I tried fixing that second fetch but still getting the same error. :(

Comment: It alters the datatype only to the first one on the list before giving that error.

Comment: I wrote a script that does this (well, close) a loonnnnng time ago. It's posted on the Resources page of my blog: http://voluntarydba.com/page/Scripts-Code.aspx `Convert text and ntext columns` Note: watch out if you have fulltext indexes on your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've re-written your SP for you with `QUOTENAME` and the `schema` like @MartinSmith suggested.  Although I'm not quite sure why you are using an SP for this.  It would seem like a stand alone piece of code without the SP wrapper would make more sense for something like this.

You use `QUOTENAME` to deal with odd characters in the name.  For example `Table-Test` is a valid table name but won't work in your code unless you put `[]`s around it  `[Table-Test]`.  `QUOTENAME` takes care of that for you.  It also handles if you happen to have ']'s in your name as well.  It generally considered a best practice when you are doing dynamic sql to include `schemas` and to use `QUOTENAME` where needed.

```
USE [EventLogic]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_SL_ConvertNtextToNvarchar]    Script Date: 08/08/2013 16:28:58 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SL_ConvertNtextToNvarchar]
AS
/*
*/
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
  DECLARE @table_schema nvarchar(128)
  DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(128)
  DECLARE @column_name nvarchar(128)
  DECLARE @totalCount int
  DECLARE @count int

  SET @totalCount = 0;
  SET @count = 0;
  SET @sql = '';

  -- Eventlogic
  DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(so.schema_id) AS table_schema, so.name as table_name, 
            sc.name as column_name
      FROM sys.objects so
      JOIN sys.columns sc ON so.object_id = sc.object_id
      JOIN sys.types stp ON sc.user_type_id = stp.user_type_id
                        AND stp.name = 'ntext'
     WHERE so.type = 'U' -- to show only user tables
  OPEN tables_cursor

  FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @table_schema, @table_name, @column_name
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE Eventlogic.'+QUOTENAME(@table_schema)+'.' + 
                    QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + 
                    QUOTENAME(@column_name) + ' nvarchar(max);'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    --PRINT @sql

    SET @sql = 'UPDATE Eventlogic.'+QUOTENAME(@table_schema)+'.' + 
                    QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ' SET ' + 
                    QUOTENAME(@column_name) + '=' + 
                    QUOTENAME(@column_name) + ' '
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    --PRINT @sql

    SET @count = @count + 1;
    IF @count > 0
      PRINT ('Eventlogic.'+@table_schema+'.' + @table_name + '.' + @column_name + ' ' + CAST(@count AS nvarchar(10)))
    SET @totalCount = @totalCount  + @count;
    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @table_schema, @table_name, @column_name
  END 
  CLOSE tables_cursor
  DEALLOCATE tables_cursor
  PRINT ('Total columns updated: ' + CAST(@totalCount AS nvarchar(10)))  

END;

GO
```

Comment: Thanks Keneth. It turned out that after closing SQL Management Studio and opening it again it worked. It seems like it kept a cached copy of the SP in memory.

Comment: @FedericoGiust I would recommend you to wrap in transaction as if something goes wrong, then you can rollback. This is more dangerous to do. Or you can just have print statements and then check them and then execute them once confirmed.

Answer (score 5):

While if you get this sorted out before you read my answer, making it unlikely to be useful for your particular case (unless you need to do this in multiple databases), I prefer string concatenation over cursors for this type of work. Primarily because you can print the string instead of executing it, verifying that at least the first 8K worth looks proper and correct.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'USE Eventlogic;';

SELECT @sql += N'
  ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
  + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
  + CASE WHEN c.system_type_id = 99 THEN ' N' ELSE ' ' END
  + 'VARCHAR(MAX)' + CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 0 THEN ' NOT NULL' ELSE '' END 
  + ';
  UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) 
    + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ';
  PRINT ''' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(REPLACE(t.name,'''','''''')) 
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' (' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY c.[object_id])) 
    + ' columns)'';'
FROM sys.columns AS c
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE c.system_type_id IN (35,99);

SET @sql += N'
PRINT ''Total columns updated: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @@ROWCOUNT) + ''';';

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

When you're happy with the `PRINT` output, uncomment the `EXEC` and run it again.

[Jon Seigel's script](http://voluntarydba.com/page/Scripts-Code.aspx) offers additional functionality (dealing with columns that participate in FULLTEXT indexes).

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your suggestion, I'll keep this in mind if we need to convert multiple columns again.

Answer (score 1):

Below is one variation that will print the statements for you to analyze and then you can run them :

```
DECLARE @CurrentDataType VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @DataTypeToChange VARCHAR(max)

SET @CurrentDataType = 'datetime'       ---CHANGE HERE !!
SET @DataTypeToChange = 'smalldatetime' ---CHANGE HERE !!

SELECT 'alter table ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(T.[object_id], DB_ID()) + '.' + T.[name] + CHAR(10) + ' alter column ' + C.[name] + ' ' + @DataTypeToChange + ' ' + CASE 
        WHEN C.[is_nullable] = 0
            THEN 'not null '
        ELSE ' null '
        END
FROM sys.[tables] AS T
INNER JOIN sys.[all_columns] C ON T.[object_id] = C.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.[types] DTY ON C.[system_type_id] = DTY.[system_type_id]
    AND C.[user_type_id] = DTY.[user_type_id]
WHERE T.[is_ms_shipped] = 0
    AND DTY.NAME = '' + @CurrentDataType + ''
ORDER BY T.[name]
    ,C.[column_id]
```

Comment: FYI [`OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME()` and other metadata functions can actually block other operations (unlike most access to catalog views and DMVs, depending on isolation level)](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/432497/metadata-functions-should-follow-same-isolation-semantics-as-metadata-queries), so I've stopped using them in favor of joins to, say, `sys.schemas`, which don't block.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good point and reference, will keep that in mind.